# Focus on textarea on webView does not open soft keyboard - kitkat 4.4

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView with one input (textarea) , I set this input focus using focus() and there's no soft keyboard on devices running android kitkat (checked 2 devices running 4.4.4).
while on devices running android lollipop(checked on 3 devices running 5.0.1 and 5.1.1) there's keyboard and everything works as expected.
webkit version is same for all devices (537.36)

any idea how can I get keyboard to show up on 4.4.4 devices?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If your App is developed by cordova  use this code

```
cordova.plugins.keyboard.show(); // for keyboard open 

cordova.plugins.keyboard.close(); or cordova.plugins.keyboard.hide(); // for closing keyboard
```

First need to add keyboard plugin

its working for me try yourself